# Scrollable dropdown on badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

On the Activity page, could we make the badges clickable to reveal a dropdown menu of the badges that we achieved under that class?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think this would clutter up the page a little, especially since we already have a Badges tab. But I do agree with separating badges by type:

- In addition to the existing recent, name, and class sorting options, you could sort badges by type (gold, silver, or bronze).
- The class sorting type would show what class the badge falls into (posting, gaining rep, etc.)
- The Badges section on the Profile tab (the tab other people see when they click on your name) would have a link called "Show all Badges", which would take them to the Badges section of the Activity page.

Because we already have a Badges section on both parts of the profile page, I think a dropdown isn't really needed, but some extra sorting options for badges are.

Comment: I like your idea of sorting badges, but implementing a badge filter can be tedious.  A point system for badges is basically a repeat of the badge symbols next to your username.  Also, just so you know, there are no badges that can be earned repeatedly. ;)

Comment: @DominatorX Thanks for your feedback, I've changed my post.